# Use of "remain short of"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Hospitals **remain short of** basic medicines, and patients are even told to bring in their own bottles — often empty Taedong Beer bottles — to use for saline drips.

I have seen this sentence . And I couldn’t understand What “ remain short of” means . Would it be okay if I say “ Hospitals remain short of basic medicines...”? I mean “Be short of”  meet this meaning in this sentence .

Answer (score 2):

To remain in a state is to stay in that state. Hospitals were previously short of (suffered a shortage of) basic medicines, and they continue to be short of them. I remain hungry, because I could not find any food. I remain anxious, because my cat still has not come home.

> remain
>   verb
>   to stay in the same place or in the same condition

[Remain (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remain)